# Jupyter can't import OpenCV when Installed on a seperate environment in anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I'm working on a new project where I need to install all necessary packages such as OpenCV on a custom environment for the sake of organized-work using anaconda.

1- First, I created and activated the new environment called OPENCV_env

[image]

2- Then I installed OpenCV on this environment

[image]

3- I added my new environment to jupyter notebook using the following command

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=OPENCV_env
```

4- I opened jupyter notebook and choase the the new kernel

[image]
[image]

5- when i try to import OpenCV in jupyter, it returns the following error:
[image]

6- I checked whether OpenCV is installed on the custom environment, and it seems to be correctly installed:

[image]

**So my question is:**
Why cv2 cant be imported in Jupyter notebook, especially when I choose the kernel environment that I created?

Comment: Have you made sure that your new kernel is set up correctly? Check `sys.executable` and `sys.path` Do they point to the environments location?

Comment: @FlyingTeller the sys.executable has one path and it points to the python.exe which is not the same path as the environment. the sys.path returns many paths which all do not include the path of the environment. what I also find to be wierd is that after checking where opencv is being installed. It turned out that its installed in the folder pkgs which in turn located in side the anaconda3 folder

Comment: That the sys.executable does not point to the python in the env means that the kernel is not set up correctly. The pkgs folder is not a folder where packages are installed, it is only a download cache. Did you run the `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=OPENCV_env` line before or after installing opencv?

Comment: @FlyingTeller. After. However, when i install opencv while im in opencv_env, its not being installed in site-packages in the opencv_env folder and instead i only locate the opencv in pkgs folder. And BTY, Ive installed other packages like numpy pillow and they have been installed correctly in the site-packages folder inside the opencv_env. So why this doesnt work for opencv lib?

Comment: It should be installed, since you can import it from the env, as can be seen in your screenshot. Try to run `print(cv2)` after the import statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem just by installing opencv from source. It also works by installing opencv through pip pkg-manager. However, i don't know why jupyter can't import the cv2 when installed using conda.
Link to the source build:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjXkW0-4gME&t=397s